# Javascript class pattern to satify JSHhint (on cloud9)?

Tags: javascript, jshint, cloud9

I'm creating Javascript classes using cloud9 but JSHint is complaining of unused locals - how do I correctly do what I want?  A minimal example is this:

```
/* jshint unused: false */
function Test(dummy) {
    var _dummy = dummy;
}

Test.prototype.interface = function() {
    this._dummy = 23;
};
```

I get `'_dummy' is defined by never used.` from JSHint running in the cloud9 editor.  I'm also puzzled by the jshint directive not working and the `this._dummy = 23;` apparently being OK.  Thanks for suggestions of further reading for me - still getting my head around Javascript ;-). I have 'Javascript The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition' to hand in case there's somethig that I've misread in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var _dummy = dummy;` line creates a **local variable** called `_dummy` inside the constructor, which you assign the parameter's value to but then never use.

You probably meant to store it as a property:

```
function Test(dummy) {
    this._dummy = dummy;
//  ^^^^^
}
```